# Security of DNS answers

Tags: security, networking, ssl, udp, dns

I have been searching for information regarding this topic but I found no direct answer.
Is it possible for the following to happen:

PC 1:
-opens UDP socket in port X
-sends a request to a DNS server to resolve a name

Meanwhile

a hacker captures the packet in the internet, and he himself answers the request with a wrong answer

Can this happen? If not, what prevents this? DNS uses SSL or another security mechanism? Do our operative systems use secure communications with DNS servers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to look into the kaminsky dns vulnerability, which is somewhat what you've described. Since then there has been plenty of material about how DNS is flawed, both conceptually and in its implementation. I have some quite interesting presentations about it, I could dig them up if you are interested. Also it should be perhaps noted that it has been now said many times that DNS was not developed with security in mind, and some kind of security layer was only added on ad hoc basis

Answer (score 3):

The scenario you present is perfectly possible. It's one of the reasons why [DNSSEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System_Security_Extensions) was invented.

DNSSEC allows the resolver client to check a chain of cryptographic signatures from any DNS record all the way up the tree to a trust anchor (which is usually the DNS root).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an HTTP web service that utilizes SSL to make sure that the answer hasn't been tampered with: `curl https://api.openresolve.com/a/stackoverflow.com`. Docs at https://www.openresolve.com